# SilverStripe not picking up unit tests

Tags: php, phpunit, silverstripe

(using SilverStripe 3)

I'm trying to set up some unit tests however the testing framework seems to not be picking up my test classes, I'm probably missing something but it's unclear as to what.

The tests are inside a module which is imported through composer.
The module has the following structure

```
/htdocs
...
/(moudulename)
    /src
        Bla.php
    /tests
        BlaTest.php
```

The BlaTest.php file contains the following

```
<?php

class BlaTest extends SapphireTest
{
    public function testCreation()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting that once I do a build and flush that I'll see the test listed in /dev/tests, however it's not showing up. This is all that I did and if I understand the documentation correctly this should be all that's needed, however the test does not show up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Running tests through the browser is a discouraged way of doing it these days, and is removed in SS4. This looks fine to me, does the test run if you run phpunit from the command line?

Comment: No tests are running on the commandline at all, /dev/tests should just display a list of runnable tests and I was hoping I'd see it in there.

Comment: running `vendor/bin/phpunit framework/tests` i get:

require_once(Zend/Log.php): failed to open stream: no such file or direcotry... however when I go looking for the file it is there.

Comment: add `'' flush=1` to the end, the CLI and browser have different caches

Comment: Also, share your phpunit.xml file - you need to make sure it includes the framework or CMS's bootstrap.php file

Answer (score 1):

The folder was missing a _config directory so SS wasn't looking in there at all.
The file tree should look like

```
/htdocs
...
    /_config
    /src
        Bla.php
    /tests
        BlaTest.php
```

There doesn't have to be anything in the `_config` directory, it just has to be present.